# Chrome default size and position when opening a new window

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome

Currently, when you open a new window of Chrome (by middle clicking the shortcut on Windows, or using Ctrl+N) it will be placed above the last opened window if there is one and will have the same size.

I usually have one or two chrome windows opened on a second screen, with specific size. When I open a new window I want it to open on the first monitor, and in a default size that is better suited to general browsing. It quickly becomes painful to move that window all the way across the two monitors and resize it... Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it can be done.  I think chrome has been hard-coded to open like that.  It ignores all the window rules of my desktop environment.